# Stochastic system vs. stochastic process

Tags: terminology, definition, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, stochastic-processes

I work on a project on stochastic diffusive systems described by stochastic differential equations (SDEs).
My background is from dynamical systems, so I tend to call the system under consideration a ***stochastic system***. However my collaborator has a statistics background, and they naturally name the systems under consideration a ***stochastic process***.

Since we are currently finishing our article, there are parts of the text where we refer to systems and parts where we refer to processes.

So I was wondering whether I can use these two terms interchangeably, or whether there are some subtle formalities that I have to consider?
Or is *stochastic system* equivalent to *stochastic process* in every respect?

Comment: I guess a stochastic system would always involve a real continuous time-parameter, while stochastic processes can be indexed by any linearly ordered set (e.g. discrete processes). However, i think the system terminology is not the most fixed one. So you should just make it clear at the beginning what you mean.

Comment: @NDewolf, I'd say a stochastic system can also be discrete - certainly in math, but even when the 'original' physical system is continuous one can often define, e.g., a Poincaré map of it.

Comment: We specify from the beginning that this is a continuous time continuous space system/process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: "Stochastic system" is probably best, but either one is fine.

First, one can investigate a deterministic (non-stochastic) system using statistical tools that treat the variables as random (even though they aren't) so, since your system truly contains a random element, this fact is made more clear by using the term "stochastic system", which makes it arguably preferable to "stochastic process".

Besides, a given system can be described by different models, and a given model can yield different measurements (variables) — hence, one can ascribe different stochastic processes to the same system: So, calling it "system" highlights it's the focus of the work and the "process" is just being used to study it.

Now, that's of course a very fine distinction, and these terms often remain loosely defined, so it's also OK to just add a remark in the beginning of the paper along the lines of "*the terms 'stochastic system' and 'stochastic process' are used interchangeably*", or even to choose either term and stick to it throughout the text.

Here are some excerpts that, besides my own experience, might support my statements above:

- [Book chapter](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-801895-8.00018-X):

> Variables that fluctuate randomly in time are called stochastic processes or random functions.

- [Lecture notes](https://www.cimat.mx/Eventos/mesd09/cursocollet.pdf):

> Although any (stationary) stochastic process can be considered as a dynamical system (with phase space the set of all possible trajectories and transformation given by the time shift), there are however some important differences to mention. First of all, it is often the case that a dynamical system has many invariant measures.

- [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stochastic_dynamical_systems):

> However, in nonlinear systems where noise acts as a driving force, noise can drastically modify the deterministic dynamics. We discuss these issues using a basic level of description which couples a stochastic process to a deterministic equation of motion: the stochastic differential equation (SDE).

- [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process):

> a stochastic (/stoʊˈkæstɪk/) or random process is a mathematical object usually defined as a family of random variables. [...]
> Stochastic processes are widely used as mathematical models of systems and phenomena that appear to vary in a random manner. [...]
> historically the word process denoted an evolution of some system in time

Comment: Thank you! 
Yes as I said I prefer the term stochastic system, but for theory parts where we derive results from stochastic analysis, my professor writes stoch. process (because that's how the theorems were defined). 
I will try to convert everything to "system" and if this doesn't work, then the footnote you mention is the best possible solution.
I asked to figure out whether a general reader understands sth different with each term, and I am missing out sth obvious by using then interchangeably, but it seems not (at least until some hardcore mathematician comes round the corner :D )

Answer (score 1):

Such terminology may vary from a (sub)field to a (sub)field. However, I would not equate a *system* with a *process*.

- *Process* is a mathematical abstraction, particularly well-defined in case of stochastic processes - it is a space of time/space variables with particular statistical properties.
- *System* is a composition of physical objects, whose behavior might be described by a stochastic process - in which case it is natural to call it *stochastic behavior* and to call the system a *stochastic system*.

Ultimately, mixing the two terms is unlikely to result in any confusion - it is more about good writing style and clear language than about physics.

Comment: System *is a composition of physical objects* – That’s not how that term is used in the field of dynamical systems, where a system can be an abstract object or model.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft as I pointed out in the first sentence, there are terms used in specific sense in some fields. Still, even in dynamical systems I would not equate the *system* (usually meaning a set of equations and related conditions) with the its time evolution/its solutions, which is a *process*.